# NSNetService delegate and ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nsnetservice

Performing the following in my app won't call the delegate:

```
NSNetService * bonjourMonitor;
    bonjourMonitor = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local." type:@"_device-info._tcp" name:@"My Mac"];
    [bonjourMonitor setDelegate:self];
    [bonjourMonitor startMonitoring];
```

I am using Automatic Reference Counting. Doing the same without ARC works perfect. NSNetService seams to be released before the delegate has been called.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where are you preforming this call? Where do you release bonjourMonitor when you are not using ARC?

Comment: @Ben: I perform this in a delegate method of a custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define bonjourMonitor as an ivar or static.